# How to add login redirection with aws cognito to my custom domain

Tags: reactjs, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have a user pool in aws cognito which I want to redirect after sign up to a url in my ReactJs application. I have created a lambda function that I use to send an email to verificate user. This is due to aws cognito does not allow to send an email verification with a custom url, in my case, to my app url.

I want to redirect to my app's dashboard after signing up without login.